# Counting memory accesses (including page tables) for a single IA32 instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, page-tables

I want to understand what is the number of memory accesses required to perform the data transfer of an instruction like:   xor (%eax),%eax
if we are in a paged system with one page table, no tlb cache and with zero page faults.
I think that we have to go first in page table and then in the frame to translate the address that is in eax and then do the xor. So i think that there are 2 memory access, but I want to be sure.

I have to count also the fetch from memory of the instruction?

And if I have two level page tables (page directory and page table) and an instruction like

```
add $10, 16(%eax)
```

i have to go to the address in eax at offset 16, sum 10 and store that value in the same memory location? So i have to do one access to page directory, one to page table and one to the frame to translate the address?

So if I have an instruction like:
`mov 4(%eax),(%ebx)`
I have to do 6 access to memory because one to page directory, one to page table and one to the frame for the two addresses in eax and ebx?

Comment: Note that `mov 4(%eax),(%ebx)` is not a valid instruction.

Comment: x86 uses multi-level page tables.  Even the legacy 32-bit non-PAE is 2-level.  So a TLB-miss / cache-miss memory source operand takes at least 3 loads, including the data itself.  Or 5 under a normal 64-bit kernel running 32-bit user-space.  You probably only want to count data accesses, not also instruction fetch.  Even 8086 had a prefetch buffer and instructions are variable-length, so you can't easily model a "naive" CPU without instruction cache in any sane way.  Fetching single bytes, and unaligned word / dword immediates / displacements, all separately would be insane.

Comment: `movsd` is a valid instruction which would have the same analysis as a hypothetical `mov 4(%eax),(%ebx)`.  (Assuming a flat memory model where ES base = DS base.)

Comment: Oh, I guess you could have legacy 2-level page tables but with 4MiB hugepages so the page directory entry is actually a hugepage entry that gives the final physical address.  https://wiki.osdev.org/Page_Tables.  Or x86-64 can have 2M or 1G hugepages so you can have 3 or 2 levels of tables instead of the usual 4.

Comment: But I haven't asked none of this, it is an hypothetical situation to better understand the page tables. It's such a theoretical machine

Comment: @loremipsum The way paging works on x86 is precisely defined.  It seems you want to describe a machine that is a bit like x86 but not completely.  This seems to confuse us all.  Perhaps it might be easier to leave the association with x86 and instead describe an entirely abstract machine to avoid any wrong assumptions.

Comment: @fuz it's what i said

Comment: @loremipsum It appears other users (me included) aren't quite sure what you mean.  So please clarify your question.